# instantiated polymorphic function as argument in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In the last line of the following, I want to instantiate a polymorphic function and pass it as an argument.

```
function id<T> (x:T) { return x; }
console.log ( id<number>(0) )
console.log ( id< (x:number)=>number > (id) (0) )
console.log ( id< (x:number)=>number > (id<number> ) (0) )
```

I am getting `error TS1005: '(' expected.`

So it seems I can instantiate the type argument only if I also call the function. Really?

Leaving out the instantiation (next-to-last line) just works.

For reference, this works in C# (note: `id<int>` ) :

```
using System;
class P {
    static T id<T> (T x) { return x; }
    public static void Main (string [] argv) {
        Console.WriteLine (id<Func<int,int>> (id<int>) (0));
    }
}
```

Well I guess it's just not possible in TypeScript. The standard 
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#4-expressions says "TypeScript augments JavaScript expressions with the following constructs: ... Type arguments in function calls ..."  and this apparently means "Type arguments only in function calls".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cleaning up the code sample to be clear about purpose. You want the following:

```
function id<T>(x: T) { return x; }
(id<(x: number) => number>(id<number>))(0);
```

Basically want to have `id<number>` as a variable. i.e.:

```
function id<T>(x: T) { return x; }
let idNum = id<number>; // This is what you want
```

That is *syntactially incorrect*. You cannot create concrete types that way. Sadly you need to use a type assertion that puts the burden of reliability on your shoulders

```
let idNum = id as {(x:number):number};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution: [use interfaces](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=function%20id%3CT%3E(x%3A%20T)%20%7Breturn%20x%7D%0Ainterface%20id%3CT%3E%20%7B%20(x%3AT)%3A%20T%3B%20%7D%0A%0Aconst%20idNum%3A%20id%3Cnumber%3E%20%3D%20id%3B%0A%0AidNum('1')%3B%0A).

```
function id<T>(x: T) {return x}
interface id<T> { (x:T): T; }

const idNum: id<number> = id;

idNum(1); // ok
idNum('1'); // gives an error
```

Another way: [use a wrapper function](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=function%20id%3CT%3E(x%3A%20T)%20%7Breturn%20x%7D%0Ainterface%20id%3CT%3E%20%7B%20(x%3AT)%3A%20T%3B%20%7D%0A%0Aconst%20idNum%3A%20id%3Cnumber%3E%20%3D%20id%3B%0A%0AidNum('1')%3B%0A).

```
function id<T>(x: T) {return x}
function idNum(x:number) { return id(x); }

idNum(1); // ok
idNum('1'); // error
```

You can substitute `number` with any type you want in both examples. Use `idNum` instead of `id<number>` wherever you want.

Answer (score -2):

Type information is used only at compile type to verify type checks. After that it is lost. For example your typescript (without last line) will be compiled to the following javascript:

```
function id(x) { return x; }
console.log(id(0));
console.log(id(id)(0));
```

As you can see there is no generic type information present anymore. Therefore you cannot reference to anything else except "id" function object.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not answer the question.